# How to make SELECT in this case?

Tags: sql-server

How to create a single MSSQL SELECT query in this case:

1. We've got 2 tables: fruits and expiration
2. The goal is to receive table where specific fruit number has information about having NULL in expirationDate column. Those fruit numbers that don't have NULL would have zeros in that column. Number 4 doesn't exist in expiration table, so it would also have 0 in results, because it doesn't have NULL.

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZHjw.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried using some LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN, but I have no clue, how to populate column expirationDate with 0's and 1's. And also the number 4 is a problem for me, because it doesn't exist in the expiration table, so my results think that 4 is also NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily get the expiration date on the format you want. However, it does not really matter(?). I assume you want 1 or 0 in your new table because you want to use an if statement to check if the fruit is bad or not.
You can solve this easily:

```
if(expirationDate == null){/*something*/}
```

or, you might even be able to do

```
if(expirationDate) //this is all fruit that is not bad
else{/*your code to deal with expirated fruit here*/}
```

Note: I don't know what programming languages you are using. But in most of them: null and 0 are FALSE.

```
if(null) // false
if(0) //false
if(undefined) //false, in javascript
//everything that is not a false value, is true.
if("oiaehgtaoiwgneawg") //true
if(-1) //true
```

To answer your SQL query question:

You already have everything you need in the *expiration* table

```
SELECT fruit_number, expiration_date
FROM expiration;
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this won't work. First of all, you will receive multiple same fruit numbers e.g 1 has two records. And secondly, if the fruit number has NULL, than it shouldn't show the other expiration date.

Comment: ah okay... I didn't quite catch that from you question. My lunch break is over right now but I will take a look after work, if no one else has solved the problem yet :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use it with `Case` Condition. But have to change statement a little:

```
select fruit_number, --distinct(fruit_number),
x =case expiration_date
when NULL then null
else 0
end
```

Answer (score 0):

My friend found the solution.

```
SELECT
    fruit_number, 
    MAX(expirationDate) as expirationDate
FROM
    (SELECT
        f.fruit_number,
        CASE
            WHEN e.expiration_date is NULL AND e.fruit_number IS NOT NULL THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS expirationDate
    FROM
        expiration as e
        FULL OUTER JOIN fruits as f ON f.fruit_number = e.fruit_number
    WHERE
        f.fruit_number IS NOT NULL
    ) t
GROUP BY
    fruit_number
ORDER BY
    fruit_number
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).